# GAE db.Model getting property instead of a string value

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a db.Model which has a string property on it, email_type. Now I've the values for type defined in a readonly class. When I save this to the datastore I get the string  instead of "Register", it also raises a BadValueError. How do I get it to save as a string, not as a property.

Here's the (slimmed down) code:

```
class EmailTypes(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__reg = "Register"
        self.__news = "NewsLetter"

    @property
    def Register(self):
        return self.__reg

    @property
    def NewsLetter(self):
        return self.__news

class Email(db.Model):
    to = db.StringProperty()
    email_type = db.StringProperty()


class Example(object)

    def do_stuff(self):
        e = Email()
        e.to = 'phil@somedomain.com'
        # This should be saving as 'Register' not a ref to the objects address
        e.email_type = EmailTypes().Register

do = Example()
do.do_stuff()
```

Comment: The code you've posted works fine. You must be doing something different in the different code you're actually observing problems in, such as `e.email_type = EmailTypes.Register` without the needed call to the class, or who knows what -- we can't debug code which actually works fine by trying to guess how it differs from other code that's broken, right?-)

Comment: It seems I've made a mess of this question. Could the mods close this out? thanks.

Comment: You can edit the question - why not just fix it?

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you change your EmailTypes class to look like this:

```
class EmailTypes(object):
    Register = 'Register'
    NewsLetter = 'NewsLetter'
```

and use it like:

```
e.email_type = EmailTypes.Register
```

Does that make your simplified example work?

Comment: Phil's code does seem very over-complicated for the problem that it is trying to solve.

Comment: @Adam - It's a simplified version - I could give you the actual problem but it seemed like overkill. All I really want to know is how to return a string instead of a reference to the property object.

Comment: @Will - yes it would but I need the `Register`, `NewsLetter` and other properties read-only.

Comment: @Phil - I think you'll have to post your more complicated code, because the simplified example you posted works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go rework this and see what I'm doing wrong. If I can't get it working I'll post the actual code. Thanks to everybody who replied.